# Check in app.config

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I want to check in my app.config file in a console application. The question is that the app.config in the server contains server folder,
For example:

```
  <add key="OutputFolderPath" value="\\ProductionServer\recordings\" />
```

However due to debugging the code in the local machine.
The publish folder is different. Usually I get latest code and modify the value manually.

```
<add key="OutputFolderPath" value="\\TestServer\recordings\" />
```

Now I add a new value which will be existing in both places, how to check in?

I haven't found "resolve conflict" when I check in, thus I can't merge the code.

Comment: I'd suggest to use "excluded files" list in tfs 2012 to exclude app.config from checking in; rather than finding a common configuration.

Comment: But I do need to add the common things to both side.

Comment: common things in the config file or other files?

Comment: In config files, I manually to merge and keep back up files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to store a template in source control that uses tokens to refer to environment-specific settings, like

```
<add key="OutputFolderPath" value="%SERVER_PATH%\recordings\" />
```

And then when deploying the package, have the installation script swap out %SERVER_PATH% with the appropriate value for the environment to which you are deploying